# What does "quite" mean before an adjective?

Tags: word-usage

I've not found a clear answer to my question below. Everything I found on the internet was too fuzzy and vague, so I hope this is not a duplicate.

In which way does the word "quite" in front of an adjective strengthen or weaken the corresponding adjective?

---

Some examples:

Consider: "I'm quite good at school."

Does this mean I am **very** good at school, or like "*good, but also not one of the best students*" or even only considerably good?

The same for this: "I can run quite fast."

I've read, that this means that I can run **not very fast**, and I've also read that it means that I can run "*very very fast, but not like Usain Bolt".*

Answer (score 2):

If you've checked the dictionary you'll have seen that there are 2, somewhat contradictory definitions for "quite":

1. to the **utmost or most absolute** extent or degree; absolutely; completely.
2. to a certain or **fairly** significant extent or degree; fairly.

In short, "quite" can mean "very" or "not so much"!

In spoken English, we tend to put emphasis on the word when we are minimising something, and perhaps draw it out with a negative inflexion, for example:

> -was the town busy?
>   -it was *quite* busy. (meaning it wasn't *very* busy)

Also, as a very general rule, we wouldn't use it to mean the highest degree unless we were using it with a strong word such as "*excellent*", "*marvellous*" or "*terrible*". With more moderate words like "good" or "bad", it tends to be added to understate. For example, "I can run *quite* fast" would probably mean *reasonably* fast; wheras "I can run quite rapidly!" sounds far more positive, and would likely be taken to mean *very fast*.

Answer (score 0):

In modern type-written English we use *italics*, **bold**, underlining, "quote marks" etc to tweak the inferred meanings of words - "just that little bit of *fine tuning*".

In spoken English, we use volume, inflection - and modifier words - when we wish to tweak a word's meaning, ever so slightly.

> Fairly, rather, quite and pretty are all degree modifiers. They are used to express the degree to which a certain quality is present. Fairly does not show a high degree of something, rather and quite do.

So **quite** emphasizes the word busy - not busy enough to be *very* busy, as Astralbee noted in that excellent answer, but more than just *busy*.

**Reference:**

https://www.englishgrammar.org/pretty/